# Would it be possible to run Discord on Macintosh System 7?

Tags: apple-macintosh, internet

I'm toying with the idea of using System 7 as my daily work station at home, most probably via Basilisk II running on some Linux flavour, but possibly on an actual Performa 5200.

One piece of modern software that I would like to keep is Discord. I know this is probably far fetched, but would it be possible to run Discord in some way on System 7? Either via a browser (which would lead to the follow up question of whether there is a "modern" browser that can run on System 7) or some other sorcery.

Comment: You might be able to run a bridge of some sort to a more 'contemporary' chat system, say irc, or a terminal client on a more modern system connected via SSH (assuming there's a client.) This is a stub of an 'answer' so I'm posting it as a comment, but it would probably sidestep issues like needing modern SSL support

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but Discord has a public API, so all sorts of "lightweight clients" ought to be possible.

Comment: @BrianH The API idea is interesting. Perhaps one approach could be a custom Web Render Proxy-sort of thing as mentioned in RETRACs answer tailored specifically to Discord.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Such a  thing would be Bitlbee. Collecting all sorts of messaging under the hood of IRC.

Comment: @BrianH It would be possible to write an Application from scratch. But this is very hard to achieve because of the lack of modern Crypto. Porting OpenSSL to a linkable library in a way that it's easy to incorporate upstream changes is a real challenge. (This is something all old OS are suffering from, not only Macs.)

Comment: looks like there's a bitlbee plugin for discord. I was thinking of a standalone client though - I run a cli client for another chat network for various reasons on a server I run and it runs fine over SSH. Still, its a bit of a frame challenge, and an old machine as a dumb terminal for a more modern system is  a pretty common workaround for unsupported protocols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no reasonably modern browsers capable of running modern web apps for System 7.  [Classilla](https://www.floodgap.com/software/classilla/) is the closest thing, and it requires Mac OS 8.6 or 9.  And I'm not sure it could handle Discord, either.

You definitely cannot run the desktop app on a classic Mac directly.

Still, I can think of a couple indirect ways to achieve what you want:

There are web proxies which render modern web pages into simple images and HTML that old browsers can handle.  See [Web Render Proxy](https://github.com/tenox7/wrp) in particular.  I haven't tested Discord, but it can handle some web applications.

Another option would be to use something like VNC to login to a remote desktop on a modern machine, running the Discord app or a web browser.

Comment: The Web Render Proxy idea is exactly the sort of unlikely, lateral solution I was hoping for. Love it. I'd mark this as the Answer, but I want to test first to make sure Discord specifically works since that is what my question is about.

Comment: If there's a discord application for Linux (I don't know), using abandoned MacX from Apple, it might be possible to run it as remote X application. My experiences running Firefox as a remote browser are very bad. MacX supports only 256 colors, and is really slow with transfers of loads of bitmaps.

Comment: I finally got around to setting this up with web render proxy and it blew me away. Chatting on Discord in Netscape 3 on Mac System 7 in 1440p resolution really messed with my head.

Answer (score 3):

*[Only a partial answer, more a collection of thoughts]*

The 5200 is about the worst PPC Mac that has there been. While having a 603, it's crippled with a 32 bus interface and an 8 bit IDE. A straight guarantee for low performance. The 601 based 6100 is faster. So performance might be a rather limiting factor.

While the 5200 was first delivered with System 7, it might be a good idea to update to 9.1, much like it's suggested to use 8.1/8.5 on 68k Macs. 9.1 improves performance considerable over 7, as most code is native PPC, not being slowed down by emulation. In addition support for many interfaces got improvements, especially all around TCP/IP integration, quite related to your project.

Which brings the next important step, a modern Browser, but there is none. The most modern browse contemporary to Mac OS 9 is the Internet Explorer 5, stalling since 2000. Netscape 7 and Mozilla 1.3 are a bit more modern, but still way behind what the discord web interface requires. Classilla is essentially Mozilla 1.3 with development up to the mid 2000s and patches until some years ago.  (I'm not sure about the state when iCab stopped development). As well not fit for the job. So no chance to run the  discord web client soon.

The last resort would be a discord application, but the earliest I find requires Mac OS X at least. Being introduced in 2015 first, Discord is simply too new for any classic Mac. In fact, not even G3 board would help, as Discord only runs on 10.9 and later, so it's x86 only.

First introduction data of a software (here 2015) is always a good indicator what OS is required, as next to noone develops new mainstream (*1) applications for long gone systems.

Comment: 8.5 cannot run on 68k Macs, and I would not advise 9.1 on a very low-end, [crippled](https://lowendmac.com/2014/power-mac-and-performa-x200-road-apples/) PowerPC like the 5200. 7.6 will get you the best performance on such a system. Run 8.1 or 8.6 if you absolutely need the newer OS to run apps.

Comment: @CodyGray 8.5 runs quite well on my most beloved Mac, my 630. It's true that 8.5 does not run out of the box, but by copying a few files from 8.1, it runs smooth. Also, 9.1 runs way faster than any 7.x on a low end PPC due containing next to no 68k anymore.

Comment: That... that cannot be true. If you're running OS 8.5 on a Quadra/Performa 630, then you surely have a PowerPC upgrade installed. Apple officially says you can't even use 8.5 with a PPC upgrade card, but you can. However, 8.5 on a 68k? I don't believe it. 8.5 introduced a PPC-native Finder. No way you're getting that on a 68k, even a 68040. If the files you're copying from 8.1 are the System and the Finder, maybe. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Well, it got a CPU card installed : A 486 DOS card  (MaybeI should try to run OS X 10.10 or later? :)). I don't remember what files I had to flip, but it wasn't much and it runs flawless since more than 20 years. 8.5 still consists in most parts of 68k code. That's also a reason why it's not great for PPC. 9.1 is way less burdened with that.

Comment: Sure you don't have a PPC logic board swapped in there? The 630 has exactly the same case as the PowerMac 6200/6300 series. The 6360 is an *awesome* PowerMac (the others in the series were horribly crippled garbage, exactly like the 5200/5300 series you mentioned). Not sure if the 486 DOS card would continue to work with a PPC motherboard swap. I guess I need to ask a new question about how you managed to got OS 8.5 to run on a 68k? That's pretty interesting to me. I spent many years up to my neck on pre-Intel Macs, running a repair shop and generally hacking. Never seen that before.

Comment: @CodyGray Pretty sure. I guess I know what's in my machines - at least the ones I do use from time to time. Also, it's a genuine 630 DOS, even written on the outside. One of the best Macs ever, maybe even better than the 475, which I like otherwise most, and way better than any of the so called high end Macs. Never managed to fill up its 132 MiB of memory :))  Getting 8.5 running did take some time and a Zip drive to try configurations. I did it around 2000 (so not a retro job), so really don't remember each step, but I was browsing thru the code forks and comparing a lot what was there.

Comment: The reason for the Performa 5200 is pure nostalgia. I have a first generation iMac in the attic as well, but it sits in an awkward spot where I'm less nostalgic for it while it's still an ancient piece of hardware in Internet-time.

Comment: @hexamon And nostalgia is always a good reason, but usage today will be rather limited. The best you may be able to (without extraordinary effort)  is surfing some a part of what's nowadays on the web using IE5, iCab or Classilla, but don't expect much. But then there are rather timeless task, like eMail or editing some text - or playing a classic game that might work for you as well.

Comment: From my decades-long experience, sometimes, the blo… wealth of new features coming with newer systems compensates for the faster PPC code. Especially with low-end machines where buses and this I/O are limited.